# Firebase database getting invalidated after 30days of builind the app. How to fix this?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

all client requests to your Firestore database will be denied. Before that time, please write strong security rules that allow your app to function while appropriately protecting your data. Analysis is run daily; if you've modified your rules in the last 24 hours, those changes may not be accounted for.

How to remove this error and run my app fluently after it crosses 30 days because I need the app....it's basically a chat app

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have to read and understand how [Firebase security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules) work, and come up with rules that meet the needs of your app.  Since we don't know how your app accesses the database, what kind of user authentication is required (if you're using authentication at all), there's nothing specific that can be said.  Just understand how to implement rules for your app.

Comment: Okay. But my app is for just one to one interaction chat app. Shoud I show my Java code here?